# How to read the Chrome chronology from file "history"

Tags: java

the SQLite history file is stored in C:...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History. How can I retrieve only two field of this database: `visits.visits_time` (converted to a Date) and `urls.url` in Java, in order to have an output like that: `https://example.com/ 2018-10-25 08:42:27`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a SQLite file you're probably going to have to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/ for querie purposes, then you can do whatever you want with it